# ComboBox text /value fill on cell click in DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

Been stuck on this for a while can't seem to find the right answer here. I'm trying to fill a selected value in my `ComboBox` any time I click on a cell to fill my details with the rows info.

```cs
private void grdUpdateEvent_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{

    Event myEvent = new Event();

    try
    {
        string strSno = grdUpdateEvent.Rows[grdUpdateEvent.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        myEvent.getAnEvent(Convert.ToInt32(strSno));
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException OoREx)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(OoREx.Message + "\n\n Row: " + grdUpdateEvent.CurrentCell.RowIndex);
    }

    //load venues details onto form

    txtID.Text = myEvent.getEventID().ToString();

    cboVenue.Text = myEvent.getVenueName();

    txtTitle.Text = myEvent.getTitle();
    txtDescription.Text = myEvent.getDescription();
    dtpDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(myEvent.getEventDate().ToString());
    dtpTime.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(myEvent.getEventTime().ToString());
    txtTicketsAvailable.Text = Convert.ToString(myEvent.getTicketsAvailable());
    txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(myEvent.getPrice());

    grpBox.Visible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you used to fill combobox, if it was just a list of string or an objet. Any way, you have to set SelectedValue ou SelectedItem instead Text.